# Tables in Markdown (in Jupyter)

Tags: markdown, jupyter

A super basic question: why is the following not rendering in Markdown - which happens to be in a `jupyter` notebook

**Raw code**

```
### Results

| --- | --- | --- |
| Stretch/Untouched | ProbDistribution | Accuracy |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Stretched | Gaussian | .843 |
```

**Code as it looks in `jupyter` in edit mode**

[image]

**Rendering in `jupyter`**

[image]

So the table did *not* render properly

**Update** I did some twiddling and now it renders.. but **still uncertain why the original code did not work**

[image]

Answer (score 205, accepted):

The first row of the table defines the headers, then the next row defines the alignment of each column.  You duplicated the alignment at the top of the table and where it's actually supposed to go.

The right Markdown should simply be what you have in your syntax, but remove the first row:

```
| Stretch/Untouched | ProbDistribution | Accuracy |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Stretched | Gaussian | .843 |
```

The `---` in between the column definitions `| |` mean that the column is unjustified.  In standard Markdown, this would align to the left of the column but in Jupyter notebook, it appears to align to the right instead.

With that, I get this table:

[image]

---

If you'd like to left align or centre align, you can use `:-` and `:-:` respectively.  Depending on what Jupyter notebook environment you're using, you will need to use `-:` to right align.

```
| Stretch/Untouched | ProbDistribution | Accuracy |
| :- | -: | :-: |
| Stretched | Gaussian | .843
```

The first column will be left-aligned, the centre column is right-aligned and the last column is centre aligned.  Interestingly using Google Colab, `---` left aligns the text:

[image]

---

## Is the alignment not working as expected in your Jupyter notebook?

This section is now outdated - the alignment should work as of this date (February 9th, 2022).  See the edit below.

<s>The alignment syntax that I've mentioned above, unfortunately, does not work as of this date (June 25th, 2020) when using local installations of the Jupyter notebook environment.  This is because of a bug in the Jupyter source where the Markdown alignment is not taken into account and all of the text is right-aligned.  See the Github issue here: https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/3919.  However, it does work using jupyterlab as well as on Google Colab.</s>

---

## Edit - February 9th, 2022

Jupyter notebook versions from 6.0.0 onwards should contain the fix.  If the alignment isn't working, please ensure that you upgrade your version of Jupyter notebook and try again.

```
pip install --upgrade notebook
```

Comment: ah so the first line is  not just redundant it's deadly.

Comment: Super. Do you know by any chance how to get the table being left aligned in the notebook? The use of the columns nearby the hyphen can control only the inner text alignment.

Comment: @AndreaMoro I'm sorry for the late reply.  Can you show me an example?

Comment: Sure ... something like this, on my Jupyter lab renders in the middle of the cell. `| X item | X Value | Coefficient | New Y |` 
`| :- | - | - | - |` 
`| 46 | 361 | 2.0577 | 6.8227 |`

Comment: Take a look at [Pandoc Pipe tables](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#tables). Not sure if this works with MD used in Jupyter Notebooks though.

Comment: @rotton it wouldn't. Thanks for the resource btw. I'll try this outside of a notebook env

Comment: @rayryeng where can i find documentation on this ;)

Comment: @Vino - https://www.markdownguide.org/extended-syntax/#tables

Answer (score 4):

One could also use HTML tags in a notebook Markdown to create the table:

```html
<table ><tr><th >Stretch/Untouched <th><th> ProbDistribution <th><th> Accuracy <tr><tr>
<tr><td> Stretched <td><td> Gaussian <td><td> .843 <td><tr><table>
```

Comment: Many things are possible ..  With five tables to build and 30 minutes to do so is this the approach you would prefer?

Comment: I would only use HTML syntax if I was truly desperate.  The reason why Markdown was invented was to avoid using HTML altogether.

Answer (score 3):

Even though this question has been answered, still dropping this here - it may help someone else. I too was not able to render tables in jupyter notebook.

Example:

```
    | | Sentence #  | Word    | POS   | Tag   |
|---:|:-------------|:-----------|:------|:------|
| 1 | Sentence: 1  | They       | PRP   | O     |
| 2 | Sentence: 1  | marched    | VBD   | O     |
```

Output:

```
| | Sentence # | Word | POS | Tag | |---:|:-------------|:-----------|:------|:------| | 1 | Sentence: 1 | They | PRP | O | | 2 | Sentence: 1 | marched | VBD | O |
```

I was not able to figure out why this was happening but for some strange reason when I enter text in the first cell of first row, it was rendering fine. So here I entered `Sno.` in the very first cell and it's working fine.

Output:

[image]

Comment: It was not rendering because it is **mandatory** to have a heading per column.  You didn't which is why it did not render.  Adding `Sno.` meant you're adding a heading in the column and that's why it rendered.

Answer (score 1):

- First set the cell to Markdown and run the below code

```html
<style>
  table {
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%; /* Adjust the width as needed */
  }
  td {
    text-align: justify;
    padding: 8px; /* Adding padding for better readability */
  }
  th
  {
    text-align: center;
  }
</style>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th> SPEED </th>
        <th> DIRECTION </th>
        <th> LOCATION </th> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Knowing the speed of a car only tells us a very small fact about the vehicle</td>
        <td>Knowing the direction and the speed gives us a better picture</td>
        <td>Knowing the location along with the direction and speed makes it even better</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th> SPEED </th>
        <th> DIRECTION </th>
        <th> LOCATION </th> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Knowing the speed of a car only tells us a very small fact about the vehicle</td>
        <td>Knowing the direction and the speed gives us a better picture</td>
        <td>Knowing the location along with the direction and speed makes it even better</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This is nice but why go through all of it when markdown does already support the tabular features?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<table ><tr><th >Stretch/Untouched <th><th> ProbDistribution <th><th> Accuracy <tr><tr>
<tr><td> Stretched <td><td> Gaussian <td><td> .843 <td><tr><table>
```