# Table expands to fill entire cell on changing one column title

Tags: jupyter-notebook, markdown

I have an issue with the table in Jupyter notebooks expanding to fill the entire cell. I searched for some solution but couldn't.

I decided to use the table in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48655801/tables-in-markdown-in-jupyter#answer-63609790) to check if it would also print the wrong way.  Here's the table with the first column headings changed:

```
|link| $a_i$  | $\alpha_i$   | $d_i$  | Tag   |
|---:|:-------------|:-----------|:------|:------|
| 1 | Sentence: 1  | They       | PRP   | O     |
| 2 | Sentence: 1  | marched    | VBD   | O     |
```

This is the layout I get with the sufficiently small widths and it is what I want.

[image: correct layout]

The issue arises when I switch from **Tag** to **$\theta_i$**

```
|link| $a_i$  | $\alpha_i$   | $d_i$  | $\theta_i$  |
|---:|:-------------|:-----------|:------|:------|
| 1 | Sentence: 1  | They       | PRP   | O     |
| 2 | Sentence: 1  | marched    | VBD   | O     |
```

The table expands to the entire length of the cell. There's a moment where I get the small size after running the markdown cell but this is fleeting and the cell switches its rendering to filling the entire cell.

[image: table that fills entire cell]

Is there something that I missing? I could create a table in Excel/Word and take a screenshot but this has me scratching my head.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea why, but changing $...$ to $$...$$ seems to fix the issue for me.